# How can I summarize a property across multiple files with jq?

Tags: jq

I have a number of JSON files that look like this:

```json
{
  "property": "value1",
  ...
}
```

What I want is an output file that looks like this:

```json
{
  "<filename1>": "<value1>", 
  "<filename2>": "<value2>", 
  "<filename3>": "<value3>", 
  ...
}
```

This can be achieved with two `jq` invocations and a shell pipe:

```sh
jq '{(input_filename):.property}' * | jq -s add
```

However, I was wondering whether this is possible with a single `jq` invocation (or any other simpler way).

I'm currently using `jq` version 1.5-1 in case it's relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `inputs` in combination with the `-n` option to sequentially access all input files.

In direct analogy, you could just create the array that would have been created by the `-s` option using `[inputs]`, and then `add` up the items as you did before:

```sh
jq -n '[inputs | {(input_filename): .property}] | add' *
```

But in a more straightforward way, you could employ `reduce` to  iteratively build up your result object:

```sh
jq -n 'reduce inputs as $in ({}; .[input_filename] = $in.property)' *
```